# copy column data to next line on when condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
attendance id         status   activity
1                     0        xyz
2                     1        abc
3                     2        abc
4                     1
```

I have a column in which id is a unique value for ex when status = 2 update the next attendance id and copy the activity of status = 2 to the next attendance id i.e. 4

How can I do that?

Comment: First decide on the database you are using and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: ok sir from the next tym i will try to live upto your expectrations. .....Now can u help me out here

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy status 0 from attendance id 1 to attendance id 2, and the status of attendanceid 2 to 3. is that right?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  It makes a difference.

Comment: I am so sorry Sir @AmanArora , I think your expectations of a **free(!)  voluntary(!)** public help forum are somewhat distorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to copy the status to the next datarow. You can use this statement. I've added some demo code to it.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(attendance_id int identity(1,1), status int, acitivity nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #temp(status, acitivity)
VALUES(0, N'xyz'),(1,N'abc'),(2,N'abc'),(3,NULL)

-- see what happens
SELECT t.attendance_id, t.status as oldStatus, ISNULL(shifting.status,t.status),t.acitivity
FROM #temp t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY attendance_id) +1 as rn 
    FROM #temp
    ) as shifting
    ON t.attendance_id = shifting.rn

-- the update itself
UPDATE t
SET status = ISNULL(shifting.status,t.status)
FROM #temp t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY attendance_id) +1 as rn 
    FROM #temp
    ) as shifting
    ON t.attendance_id = shifting.rn

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```